# how to use search in EnhancedGrid plugin in dojo?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

i am searching some data in the rows dynamically....so for this i hav used  "dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Search .... but i am not getting any icon of search and i don't know how to use this plz suggest here is my code

```
           grid = new EnhancedGrid({
                           id:'grid',
                           store : yourStore,
                           structure : layout,
                           rowSelector: '20px',
                           plugins: {
                             search:true,
                             pagination: {
                                    pageSizes: ["50","100"],
                                    description: true,
                                    sizeSwitch: true,
                                    pageStepper: true,
                                    gotoButton: true,
                                    maxPageStep: 2,
                                    position: "bottom"


                                },
                                filter: {
                                    closeFilterbarButton: true,
                                    ruleCount: 5,
                                    itemsName: "rows"
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        grid.placeAt("myGrid");
                        grid.startup();
```

Comment: @MiBrock yes i worked with that but i need to know about search......cant i do with search????

Answer (score 0):

It's shown [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/enhanced/test_enhanced_grid_search.html). Just look at the source.